# How do I manipulate the javascript code to have three different dropdown menus in my navbar which don't interfere with each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one dropdown working, but the second dropdown interferes with the first one. Still very new to JavaScript and don't have time to learn it properly at the moment, so help is much appreciated!

**Dropdown CSS**

```
.dropdown{
    display:inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 100%;  
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #FFA036;
    color:black;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

**Navigation bar HTML**

I have one dropdown working well, but as soon as I put a second one in, it interferes with the first. I also have links in the bar which don't need dropdowns.

```
<nav>
    <a href="link"> Link </a>
  
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()"> Link
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
  
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()"> Link
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
            <a href="Link">Link</a>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <a href="Link"> Link </a>
    <a href="Link"> Link </a>
    <a href="Link"> Link </a>
    <a href="Link"> Link 
    </a>
</nav>
```

**JavaScript**

I think what is going wrong is something in the JavaScript here. A simple fix to make the JavaScript apply to all dropdowns would be great!

```
<script>

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
        if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function myFunction(event) {
        var parentDiv = event.target.parentNode;
        var currentDropdown = parentDiv.querySelector(".dropdown-content");
        currentDropdown.classList.toggle("show");

        var dropdownContent = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown .dropdown-content");
        dropdownContent.forEach(function (dropdownContentItem) {
            if (currentDropdown != dropdownContentItem) {
                dropdownContentItem.classList.remove("show");
            }
        })
    }

    window.onclick = function (e) {
        if (!e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('dropdown')) {
            var dropdownContent = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown .dropdown-content");
            dropdownContent.forEach(function (dropdownContentItem) {
                dropdownContentItem.classList.remove("show");
            })
        }
    }
```

```html
<nav>
        <a href="link"> Link </a>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction(event)"> Link
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction(event)"> Link
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
                <a href="Link">Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a href="Link"> Link </a>
        <a href="Link"> Link </a>
        <a href="Link"> Link </a>
        <a href="Link"> Link
        </a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use identical IDs for multiple elements.

```js
var prevMenu = null; //we will store last opened menu here
function myFunction(link)
{
  var menu = link.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0];
  if (!menu)
    return;

  if (prevMenu && prevMenu !== menu)
    prevMenu.classList.remove('show'); //close previous menu

  prevMenu = menu;
  menu.classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn') && prevMenu) {
    prevMenu.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown 
      {display:inline-block;
      }

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 100%;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #FFA036;
  color:black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="link"> Link </a>
  
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction(this)"> Link1
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="Link">sub Link 1.1</a>
    <a href="Link">sub Link 1.2</a>
    <a href="Link">sub Link 1.3</a>
  </div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction(this)"> Link2
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="Link">sub Link 2.1</a>
    <a href="Link">sub Link 2.2</a>
    <a href="Link">sub Link 2.3</a>
  </div>
  </div> 
  
  <a href="Link"> Link </a>
  <a href="Link"> Link </a>
  <a href="Link"> Link </a>
  <a href="Link"> Link 
  </a>
</nav>
```